# Why Anuloma marriage is encouraged but Pratiloma marriage is discouraged?

Tags: marriage, caste-system

Anuloma marriage means higher Varna men marrying lower Varna women. Pratiloma marriage means lower Varna men marrying higher Varna women. What is the reason behind encouraging Anuloma and discouraging pratiloma marriage?

Comment: Good Qn. Related: [Examples of Anuloma and Pratiloma marriages?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9914/1049). This is more to do with the intellectual level. A man should not marry a woman of higher intellect. See [this related post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20478/1049). Actually *Pratiloma* marriage is punishable in some of the scriptures. Hence a good family girl running away with driver or a wealthy girl from well to do family falling in love with a mechanic, would be acceptable in movies only. :-)

Comment: Varnasankaras are product of intercaster marriages. In the first chapter of the Gita, Arjun described that such varnashankars destroy the 'kukadharma' and take the members of the whole'kula' to hell. Manu says: one reason of varnasankara is a marrige between a lower caste boy and a higher caste girl.

Comment: According to the Naradasamhita, also such pratiloma marriage creates varnasankaras. Note that Aryuna mentions kuladharma as saswata ie eternal ie something which must be preserved.

Manu accepts anuloma marriage (स्त्रीरत्नं दुष्कुलादपि).Tantrasaara says that if a shudra male marries a brahmin girl, he becomes a chandala.

Answer (score 3):

We have Varna system. As per this, Apastamba Dharmasutra 1.1.1.4-5 says:

> [There are] four castes Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, Vaishya, and Shudra.
>   Among these, each preceding (caste) is superior by birth to the one
>   following.

So, it says:

1. For a Shudra, preceding varna Brahmana, Kshatriya and Vaishya are
   superior.
2. For a Vaishya, Preceding varna Kshatriya and Brahmana are superior.
3. For a Kshatriya, Preceding varna Brahmana is superior.

And among husband and wife, husband has the superior authority. But if Pratiloma marriage and takes place, we don't know who is superior(The girl is because she belongs to higher Varna or the boy is because he is the husband). So Anuloma marriage is recommended and Pratiloma marriage is discouraged.

Comment: Nice. Your logic about *Pratiloma* marriage creating the confusion due to gender superiority & division (*varna*) superiority seems correct to me. However, it will be good if you have some sources to back up. Though I feel that it's less likely to find such.

Comment: @iammilind Today only this stroke my mind. So I answered my own question. But I have never read in any scriptures that because of this or that  reason, Pratiloma marriage is not allowed.

Comment: @Yogi why you added are don't know?

Comment: @Ajay Corrected it.

Comment: -1 'But it doesn't mean Pratiloma marriage are not allowed' Dharma Shastras Gruhya sutras clearly indicate that the Children born of Pratiloma marriage are not eligible for any of the Shrauta or Smartha karmas and they are outcastes like Suta, Chandala etc.

Comment: @yogi yes, I know.

Comment: @yogi pratiloma marriage is discouraged but it doesn't mean  it is not allowed

Comment: @Ajay, it's like saying 'stealing is discouraged, but doesn't mean it is not allowed.. it just means that you'll be put in jail if you steal'

Comment: @ram I understand. Pratiloma marriage is discourage, it doesn't mean it is not allowed.(I don't agree for intercaste marriage). But stealing is prohibited.

Comment: @Ajay, no you don't understand. There is nothing called 'prohibited'. Stealing is also not prohibited. All shastras say is that, if you steal, you will be punished. It is up to you to decide whether you want punishment or not. Same way, if you do pratiloma marriage, progeny is outcasted. It is up to you to decide.

Comment: @Ajay, there is naraka for all types of papa, and svarga for all types of punya. If you do charity, good will come to you. if you steal, bad things will happen. It is up to you to decide. That is what allowed and prohibited means. So, stealing, pratiloma, varna-sankara etc. are all 'prohibited' because bad things will happen to the doer.