# Who are chandalas?

Tags: caste-system, varnashrama

When chandalas are mixed caste then they worship Hindu gods, what is chandalas relation with Hinduism. Are chandalas foreigners.

Comment: Chandala not foreigner. Chandala 100% Indian 100% Hindu. Chandalas tend to shamshan Bhumi and dead bodies.

Comment: You can read in answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22139/20129. If you like Rickross’ answer, press up arrow for vote up in answer. Answer explains child of Sudra man + Brahmin woman = chandala.

Comment: When why we should keep discrimination on chandala

Comment: Chandala live outside village. Chandala live near shamshaan bhumi, work with dead body, help making funeral fire, drink alcohol, make dog eat dead body leftover part, chandala eat food cooked from funeral pyre’s fire. That’s why some people to avoid getting impure do discrimination. But it is wrong to do discrimination. Earlier people used to give gold silver to chandala. Now no one give.

Comment: Now also chandalas are there

Comment: Yes now also chandalas are there. Shamshan bhumi workers are chandalas

Comment: We should not that touch them

Comment: Do chanadala are aryans

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Chandala i think is defined in Smritis as the varna-sankar progeny born to a Shudra man and Brahmin woman. The people who work at crematorium are from Dom jaati and they are the same since Raja Harishchandra’s time..

Answer (score 5):

As per [Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b013.htm):

> If a Sudra unites with a woman belonging to the foremost of the four orders [i.e. Brahmana], the son that is begotten is called a Chandala.

So Chandala is a mixed-cast. There are many [mixed-casts due to Anuloma and Pratiloma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35225/12304) marriages. Thus, Chandalas and other mixed-casts are not foreigners.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Chandala being born of a Sudra father and a Brahmana mother is not correct. These fanciful Smriti concepts are clearly wrong and are against the Vedas. This is clear from the Chandogya Upanishad definition of Chandala.

> Those whose conduct here has been good will quickly attain a good
> birth (literally womb), the birth of a brahmin, the birth of a
> Ksatriya or the birth of a Vaisya. But those whose conduct here has
> been evil, will quickly attain an evil birth, the birth of a dog, the
> birth of a hog or the birth of a chandala.

**Chandogya Upanishad V.10.7**

As you can see Chandogya Upanishad is specifying conduct as the reason for different births. It has nothing to do with the caste of the father or the mother.

**What does the Chandogya Upanishad verse mean?**

It has nothing to do with the caste system invented by the Smriti writers. It means that depending on the amount of good conduct a person will be born to parents of high Sattva Guna (Brahmin), to parents of middling Sattva Guna (Ksatriya) or parents of high Rajasa Guna mixed with some Sattva Guna (Vaisya). The vast majority of persons with neither good nor bad conduct will be born of parents who do not have the gunas of Brahmanas or Ksatriyas or Vaisyas but whose conduct is not as bad as that of animals.

Those whose conduct has been exceptionally bad without any redeeming feature will have animal parents or human Chandala parents. This suggests that Chandala is defined as a person whose conduct is like an animal.

**Why do the Smriti authors invent such fanciful tales?**

The reason is that the Smriti authors were seeing a torrent of inter-varna marriages. They had a choice. They could point out like Yudhisthira that the whole hereditary caste system is no longer valid or they could invent new castes. They chose the second option.

I am posting Yudhisthira's statement.

> Yudhisthira said, " In human society, O mighty and highly intelligent
> serpent, **it is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of
> promiscuous intercourse among the four orders. This is my opinion. Men
> belonging to all orders (promiscuously) begat offspring upon women of
> all the orders. And of men, speech, sexual intercourse, birth and
> death are common.** And to this the Rishis have borne testimony by using
> as the beginning of a sacrifice such expressions as -- of what caste
> server may be, we celebrate the sacrifice. Therefore, those that are
> wise have asserted that character is the chief essential requisite ...
> whatsoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous conduct, him
> have I, ere now, designated as a Brahmana.

**Mahabharata Aranya Parva Section CLXXIX**

I feel obliged to answer the remark made in the comment section even though it was a low level personal attack. The smriti writers clearly savaged the Vedic Rishis by discarding their conception of the Varna system. These medieval writers introduced dozens of 'varnas' not in the Vedas, added the idea that marriage between people of different Varna give rise to a third varna. None of these ideas are there in the Vedas.

It is these smriti writers who dumped the Vedic ideas about Varna. Can anyone show any deviation from the 4-Varna system in the Vedas? Can anyone show that the idea that the marriage of 2 persons leads to children of a third Varna is in the Vedas? The ideas of the smriti writers are also in variance with the 'guna and karma' explanation of Lord Krishna.

So whether I know less or more than these writers about the Vedas is immaterial.
The question that needs to be asked is whether these Smriti writers who cooked up fanciful schemes in disagreement with the Vedas know more about the Vedas than Lord Krishna.

A Hindu is under no obligation to accept blindly the views of anyone. Even Lord Krishna does not demand blind acceptance of His teaching in the Gita:

> ...Reflecting on this entire teaching, do as you think fit.

**Gita 18.63**

The only obligation that a Hindu has is to Truth. The reason for that is given in the Upanishads.

> satyam eva jayate nanrtam..
>
> Truth alone conquers, not untruth.

**Mundaka Upanishad III.I.6**

These Smriti writers have done a great deal of disservice to Hinduism by dumping the Vedas.

Comment: Do chandalas are aryans

Comment: Do you can give any other example plz

Comment: Any human being born anywhere on Earth whose conduct is animal like is a Chandal. The people working in the cremation grounds cannot be called Chandal without studying their conduct. In fact their self less service in cremating bodies day after day suggest that they are of high varna,

Comment: "These fanciful Smriti concepts are clearly wrong and are against the Vedas." -- These Smritis were written by Vedic Rishis. So they know about Vedas much more than you do. Isn't it? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Let us not make personal attacks.

Comment: Looking down on dharmācāryas, is not something great tbh. As @Rickross has clearly stated, these smr̥tis which you look down upon, are composed by the R̥ṣis only. What they state is dharma and satya. Disregarding their vacana is sheer folly. And they understand Veda more than you, who just relies on colonial and post colonial translations and interpretations of Veda.

Comment: And please don't put false accusations, he didn't do any personal attacks, instead he just stated a fact. You don't know Veda more than Manu, Yājñavalkya, Parāśara, Vasiṣṭha, Āpastamba, Baudhāyana, etc.